# How to serve first Nginx regex server_name servers

Tags: nginx, routing, configuration

I have a Nginx config which look like this :

```
server {
  server_name sub2.sub1.example.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name sub2.sub1.example.com;

  ... 
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^sub2\.sub1\.example\.com/toto/[abc]/.*$;

  ...
}
```

The Nginx documention says that Nginx evaluates `server_names` in the following order (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) :

> 1. exact name
> 2. longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. *.example.org”
> 3. longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
> 4. first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

So, my server with the regex `server_name` will be evaluate last (in fact, will never be evaluated because the `sub2.sub1.example.com` match first)

Is there a way to prioritize the server which have a regex as server_name ?
Is the default_server directive do this ? It's not realy what the documentation seems to say.
Maybe I should use `location` instead of different `server` directives to resolve this problem ?

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.

It's better to use some `location` directives for this problem.

So, now my config is :

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name sub2.sub1.example.com;

  ##### Non HTTPS conf #####
  location ~* ^/toto/[abc]/ {
    # This replace the "server_name ~^sub2\.sub1\.example\.com/toto/[abc]/.*$;" config block
    ...

  }

  ##### HTTPS conf #####
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name sub2.sub1.example.com;

  ...
}
```

Comment: That's not that it's better or anything. The `server_name` directive purpose is to match request's `Host` header, not the request-line URI at all.